# Find the value of $p$ such that the function sums to a twice-continuous differentiable function of $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a bounded real sequence $\{a_n\}$, for what values of the real exponent $p$ can you be sure that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^p} \sin(nx)$$
sums to a twice-continuous differentiable function of $x$? Explain your answer.

**Attempt:** We note that $|a_n| < M$ where $M>0$. We also know that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{mx}=\frac{\sin{((n+1)\theta/2)\sin{(n\theta/2)}}}{\sin{(\theta/2)}}$
Thus $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{nx}|$ is bounded. Now for $\delta >0$ , $n^{-\delta} \downarrow 0$ and thus by Dirichlet, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^p} \sin(nx)$ converges uniformly.

**I am stuck here. How do I find value of $p$ to be twice differentiable?**

Comment: see here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf care must be taken. You need the $p$ to offset the power of $n$ that will come out in the numerator when you differentiate $\sin(nx)$

Comment: So you would be using Theorem 2 in the document you shared right? And P>2 coz we are differentiating twice?